# Integrating and sharing video on vimeo ios6 ios7

Tags: ios6, ios7, vimeo

i would like to integrate vimeo in my ios app which i am developing. I wonder if is it possible to share video on vimeo after integration. I searched for any document or steps but none helped me out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "share video on vimeo" in more details?

Comment: just like we share video on facebook, the same way i want to share on vimeo

Comment: Do you want to upload a video to Vimeo via IOS? This is different than the concept of sharing.

Comment: ok then how can i upload a video to vimeo? And also but it should from the app i am creating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean uploading (as mentioned in the comments), the upload documentation is located here https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#streaming.

Comment: Document talks about javascript and action script. CAn I get small example for Objective C with oauth 2.0? Thanks.

Comment: JS and actionscript are for the client side player. There are upload examples in all of our official libraries, and many unofficial libraries: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries

Comment: Actually I am not looking to upload video. I want to download all channels and video id. I have created app and found "Client Identifier", "Request Token URL", "Authorize URL", "Access Token URL". Now I am not sure How to go about. Earlier in oauth 1.0 I was getting "Access Token" and "Token Secret". Here is my question over this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523860/vimeo-integration-to-ios-oauth-2-0