# Vimeo integration to ios oauth 2.0

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, vimeo

We had vimeo integrated using oauth 1.0. Now its not working and have to use oauth 2.0. 
I found https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client. But do not understand how to use it for vimeo.

Our earlier code was

```
OADataFetcher *fetcher;
    consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc]initWithKey:[dicVimeoInfo objectForKey:@"ConsumerKey"] secret:[dicVimeoInfo objectForKey:@"ConsumerSecret"]];

    NSURL *vimeoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:kVimeoRestURL];

    OAToken *token=[[OAToken alloc]initWithKey:[dicVimeoInfo objectForKey:@"AccessToken"] secret:[dicVimeoInfo objectForKey:@"AccessTokenSecret"]];

    request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:vimeoURL
                                              consumer:consumer
                                                 token:token
                                                 realm:nil
                                     signatureProvider:nil];

    OARequestParameter* formatparameter = [OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"format" value:@"json"];
    OARequestParameter* methodParameter = [OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"method" value:@"vimeo.channels.getAll"];


    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: formatparameter, methodParameter, nil];
    [request setParameters:params];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request prepare];
    fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];
```

Now Vimeo has shifted to oauth 2.0. I have created app and found "Client Identifier", "Request Token URL", "Authorize URL", "Access Token URL". Now I am not sure How to go about. Earlier in oauth 1.0 I was getting "Access Token" and "Token Secret".

**Edit**

I tried this. I have access token for single user. vimeo documents says we send header like "`curl -H "Authorization: bearer <OAUTH_TOKEN>" https://api.vimeo.com`" How can i do it.

```
   consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc]initWithKey:@"456a8852ebd72760de4d2206bab3dad0db35a66b" secret:@"eb74abb5d1f38ad0bd570d24e4d1d0ee3a447534"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2"];

    request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                              consumer:consumer
                                                 token:nil
                                                 realm:nil
                                     signatureProvider:nil];

    [request setParameters: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"method" value:@"vimeo.channels.getAll"],[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"format" value:@"json"], nil]];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bearer %@",@"a75a63c0e0121b0704a4c98d6e209eb2"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request

                         delegate:self

                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)

                  didFailSelector:nil];
```

**Edit**
I tried without client key and secret also.

```
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.channels.getAll"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bearer %@",@"7c7139ec99fa9e09f77dd2512780c301"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error: &error];

    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Response : %@", JSONDictionary);
```

**output** is same

```
Response : {
    err =     {
        code = 401;
        expl = "The consumer key passed was not valid.";
        msg = "Invalid consumer key";
    };
    "generated_in" = "0.0020";
    stat = fail;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supplying the parameters as part of a JSON object but the `client_credentials` flow is actually defined as using a plain POST with `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Hence Vimeo won't recognize a valid request at its token endpoint. Check the example in the spec at: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2

Comment: Can you give me an example.

Comment: instead of a POST body looking like `{ "grant_type" : "client_credentials", "scope" : "public" }` your POST body should be `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public`

Comment: I tried  NSString* str=@"grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public";
NSData *jsonData =[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request1 setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request1 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPost]];
    NSError *error = nil;

    [request1 setPostBody:(NSMutableData*)jsonData];

Comment: here's a tested piece of sample code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/120160d3475893626197

Comment: re. your edit on how to send the token: you don't need to use the consumer key/secret on the API call, just set the `Authorization: bearer <token>` header

Comment: Problem was in URL. URL and responses are also changed by vimeo. Use this url to get all channels https://api.vimeo.com/me/channels

Answer (score 1):

The URL's you are using are all part of the old API. All requests using oauth2 go through the https://api.vimeo.com subdomain. You can read more at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication